Image Texture Via Spotlight Not Reflecting Onto Wall
Working on a project irl that requires splitting projector imaging via mirrors. I am testing features in Blender and I can't get my spotlight using an image texture to reflect off of the mirror surface I created and "project" onto the wall. The plane is reflecting as we see the floor seam in camera view, but the image from the spotlight is not presented onto the wall, just white light.
First, is it even possible to get this to work in Blender? If so, what could I change to get it to work right?
Find relevant (and possibly irrelevant) settings below:
Working in Supported GPU Cycles
Render Properties:
32 Total Bounces, 24 Glossy; 10.00 Indirect Light Clamping; Reflective Caustics is on
Spotlight:
Color FFFFFFFF; 1000 W; Multiple Importance is on; Ray Visibilities are all on; Shader Nodes are below

Mirror Plane:
Standard plane with glossy BSDF shader; Metallic 1.000; Roughness 0.000; IOR 1.5
I also scaled everything before render
